# How to update TipTap content dynamically with Vue 3?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, tiptap

I was able to set the initial value of the content from the editor with the value of a ref, but it doesn't update the content when the value of the ref changes.

Would anyone have an idea how to do it?

```
<editor-content
  :editor="editor" 
  v-model:content="
/>
```

```
<script setup>
  import { ref } from 'vue'
  import { useEditor, EditorContent } from '@tiptap/vue-3'
  import StarterKit from '@tiptap/starter-kit'

  const generatedText = ref('<p>Hello!</p>')

  /* editor */
  const editor = useEditor({
  content: generatedText.value,
  extensions: [
    StarterKit,
  ],
  onUpdate: ({editor}) => {
     generatedText.value = editor.getHTML()
    }
  })
</script>
```

Sorry if the question is too silly, I couldn't find an answer in the documentation.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I watched for the editor, then set the content:

```
import { watch } from 'vue'
import { useEditor } from '@tiptap/vue-3'

const editor = useEditor({
    content: ''
})

watch(editor, () => {
  editor?.value?.commands.setContent('<p>Hi Mars</p>')
})
```

Answer (score 1):

How will the generatedText be generated? Through tiptap?

The v-model of tiptap is the editor.content value. You could give it an initial state but if you want to change the editor.content after some interaction with the wysiwyg (like *onFocus*) you could use: [setContent](https://tiptap.dev/api/commands/set-content)

Or maybe this helps:
[Listening for changes](https://tiptap.dev/guide/output#listening-for-changes)